# Extract the index value from array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have an array A1 with shape 2x3 & list A2. I want to extract the index value of array from the list.

Example

```
A1 = [[0, 1, 2]
     [3, 4, 5]] # Shape 2 rows & 3 columns

A2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now, I want to write a code to access the an element's index in Array A1

Expected Output

```
A2[3] = (1,0) #(1 = row & 0 = column) Index of No.3 in A1
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: are the values in `A1` relevant? In other words, do you need to _find by value_ where an element is, or do you need simply to get the index corresponding to a location? The example is ambiguous in that both arrays are various shapes of the same `np.arange(6)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use *numpy*, check out [argwhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
a1 = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
a2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
a3 = np.argwhere(a1 == a2[3]).squeeze() # -> (1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is some ambiguity in the question. Are we looking for the indices of elements by value, or by order?

#### Unravel an ordinal index

**Assuming** that the values in `A1` are not important (i.e. this is **not** a search of certain values, but really finding the index corresponding to a location), you can use [`unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) for that.

Example:

```py
>>> np.unravel_index(3, A1.shape)
(1, 0)
```

Or, on the whole `A2` in one shot:

```py
>>> np.unravel_index(A2, np.array(A1).shape)
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

which you may prefer as a list of tuples ("transpose" of the above):

```py
>>> list(zip(*np.unravel_index(A2, np.array(A1).shape)))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

#### Search for a value

If, instead, you are **searching for values**, e.g., where in `A1` are there values equal to `A2[i]`, then, like in @dc_Bita98's answer:

```py
>>> tuple(np.argwhere(A1 == A2[3]).squeeze())
(1, 0)
```

If you want all the locations in one shot, you need to do something to handle the fact that the shapes are different. Say also, for sake of illustration, that:

```py
A3 = np.array([9, 1, 0, 1])
```

Then, either:

```py
>>> i, j, k = np.where(A1 == A3[:, None, None])
>>> out = np.full(A3.shape, (,), dtype=object)
>>> out[i] = list(zip(j, k))
>>> out.tolist()
[None, (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]
```

which clearly indicates that the first value (`9`) was not found, and where to find the others.

Or:

```py
>>> [tuple(np.argwhere(A1 == v).squeeze()) for v in A3]
[None, (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 1)]
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre D Thanks for the solution, I have another Question. Is it possible to get index of all the values of list present in the array.?? Let say if list A2 is having only 0,1,3 elements Then it should give output as (0,0), (0,1), (1,0).

Comment: Also, When list is having float elements, unravel_index is giving an error  ´''Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'same_kind' ´ how to solve this error when 3 is 3.0 ??

Comment: see modified answer. Also, if `A2` contains floats, and you want to use them as indices, they should be converted to `int` first: `A2.astype(int)`. I added the case where you are looking for *values* instead of position.

Comment: Thank you so much @Pierre . Is it possible to get all locations in one shot with 'list', You explained in your modified answer with an array. Can it be also done by list?

Comment: yes, that would be the 3rd code snippet in my answer, isn't that what you are looking for?